# sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

Tags: php, terminal, phpmyadmin, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux mint and i tried to install phpmyadmin but it get an error like

```
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using       
  │ password: NO)
```

I tried to uninstall using following commend

```
sudo aptitude purge phpmyadmin
```

Then again installed using

```
apt-get -y install phpmyadmin
```

But still i get an error like

```
 Configuring phpmyadmin ├────────────────────────┐
  │                                                                          │ 
  │ An error occurred while installing the database:                           
  │                                                                            
  │ ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using       
  │ password: NO) . Your options are:                                          
  │  * abort - Causes the operation to fail; you will need to downgrade,       
  │    reinstall, reconfigure this package, or otherwise manually intervene    
  │    to continue using it. This will usually also impact your ability to     
  │    install other packages until the installation failure is resolved.      
  │  * retry - Prompts once more with all the configuration questions          
  │    (including ones you may have missed due to the debconf priority         
  │    setting) and makes another attempt at performing the operation.         
  │  * retry (skip questions) - Immediately attempts the operation again,      
  │    skipping all questions. This is normally useful only if you have        
  │    solved the underlying problem since the time the error occurred.        
  │                                                                            
  │                                  <Ok>                                      
  │                                                                          │ 
  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Please help me.Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a mysql server running on your machine?

Comment: well, you have to configure it with *valid credentials*.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i am a beginner i tried it and i didn't get result.That's why am ask here?why you down vote it?